# CHROME is not rendering some svg

Tags: google-chrome

I have a page with a lot of small svg embded (337 exactly)

all like this :

```
<img src="/path/sub_path/svg-1.svg">
```

url is relative and all svg are in the same directory

most of them work, but 2 of them are displayed as broken iamge (they appear 16 times for the first and only 1 time for the second).

[image]

**If I open them in a new tab they are well displayed.**
**The same page in Firefox works too.**

In the network panel the response headers is the same for any SVG (content-length is ok) :

[image]

but in the "response" tab instead of seeing the svg as text, I get :

[image]

I have no idea what is wrong, is there some kind of limit ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the issue

The file is in ISO-8859-1 but contains the text : °C

th "°" is encoded in utf-8, and prevent Chrome from displaying the svg at all.